# Что значит выражение "на мази"?

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "на мази" и что оно значит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изначально это выражение касалось только средств передвижения на полозьях: лыж, саней. Перед использованием полозьев их натирали специальными мазями, чтобы полозья лучше скользили.
Сейчас выражение применяется в значении "дело готово", "все хорошо"

Answer (score 4):

Можно сравнить с синонимичным фразеологизмом "как по маслу", то есть без препятствий, с максимальным комфортом.

Comment: Не совсем синонимичны. Одно дело "без препятствий, с максимальным комфортом", другое — "окончательно налажено, готово".

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, связано со смазыванием осей/колёс телеги, чтобы лучше ехала, и это отсылка к колёсной мази (дёгтю)

Answer (score 0):

> Выражение *на мази* первоначально применялось к повозкам и вообще к тем орудиям или средствам передвижения, которые смазывались перед поездкой. У Лажечникова в «Ледяном доме» встречается поговорочный афоризм: «... без мази и воз с места не тронется...» (гл. 4). У Даля в «Пословицах русского народа» (с. 620) отмечено выражение: «У меня дело на чеке, на мази» (М., 1862).
>
> Переносно *на мази* значило: "скоро уедет", "уже окончательно налажено к отправлению, к ходу, к движению, к поездке".

[В. В. Виноградов. История слов. Часть](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vinogradov.php?id=na_mazi&vol=1)